# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT when trying to switch view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController")
        self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My code complies fine, however when I hit the third line in that sequence my whole application crashes and I get a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT on that line and this is what appears in the console:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This only happens when I try to switch view controllers programmatically. I can switch view controllers normally by connecting buttons to view controllers in the storyboard, but I cannot successfully transition view controllers without having the user hit a button. Does anyone know how to fix this error, or an easier way to transition between view controllers.

Edit: I have also tried this:

```
       let nextViewController = mainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.present(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Which also did not work but still compiled just fine.

Edit 2:
Before the main error message I get this warning in the console:

objc[45953]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace (0x127e2d4d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference (0x126f7be38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: @hardikparmar I think this is the exception: Printing description of mainStoryboard.isa:
(Class) isa = UIStoryboard
Printing description of mainStoryboard:
(NSObject) ObjectiveC.NSObject = <out of scope>

Comment: Your error message is missing the important part. What's before that message, between `Terminating... NSUnknownException` and `terminating... NSException`.

Comment: @Larme I am not sure if that error message has to do with the same thing but I have edited my original post with the error message

Comment: Ok. Just after `let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController")`, write `printf("it will crash")` and show us the message console between "it will crash" to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set the "Storyboard ID" in your for the view controller in your storyboard.

[image: Screen shot of Interface Builder]